# 'y' as a vowel in German

Tags: pronunciation, vowel

I encountered the word "Typ" (en:type) which has a 'y' serving as a vowel; in this case a 'ü', I believe.

Is this a singular case or are there more words in which 'y' is used as a vowel?

Comment: Yes, the [letter `Y`](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y) is part of the standard German alphabet. Is there anything further than that you like to know?

Comment: Consider it a surrogate vowel like it's also done in English: syllable, cylinder, bicycle.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Essentially, the letter "y" itself is no vowel in the German Language. The letter that are vowels in German are:

> a, ä, e, i, o, ö, u, ü <sup>[WIKIPEDIA](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vokal#Vokalbuchstabe)</sup>

<sub>(On Wikipedia there is also mentioned É == ee, as in "*[Varieté](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Variete)*" .)</sub>

Moreover, they WIKI article says that the letter "y" can be accounted as a vowel, since its pronunciation is often like the German "ü". In some circumstances it is pronounced as "j" (*), but in some cases that's true for "i" and "u", too (e.g. Qualle  [ˈkvalə])

Strictly speaking, we have to consider the way how we pronounce the letter. That is, in "*Typ*" the vowel is a long *ü*.

> Das Deutsche ist, was das Lautinventar betrifft, eine der vokalreichsten Sprachen der Welt. Zu den Vokalen des Standarddeutschen gehören der i-Laut in „Igel“, der i-Laut in „Iltis“, der e-Laut in „Eva“, der ä-Laut in „Käse“ (siehe unten), der e-Laut in „Esra“, der mit dem Buchstaben e wiedergegebene Laut in „Ute“, der a-Laut in „Pate“, der a-Laut in „Paste“, der o-Laut in „Ton“, der o-Laut in „von“, der u-Laut in „Ute“, der u-Laut in „Bus“, **der ü-Laut in „Tüte“**, der ü-Laut in „Küste“, der ö-Laut in „Flöte“, der ö-Laut in „öfter“ und der dem kurzen a-Laut ähnliche, aber doch klar von ihm unterschiedene Vokal am Ende des Wortes „Leder“ (durch die Buchstabenkombination „er“ repräsentiert; im Unterschied zu Schreibung und Aussprache des Wortes „Leda“). <sup>[WIKIPEDIA](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vokal)</sup>

<sub>(The bold part is the vowel which covers "*Typ*".)</sub>

For that reason, we **can count "y" as vowel**. Though, note please that the *y* just occurs in adopted words from different languages. Words that are borrowed from Greek are pronounced as "ü". In all other cases the "y" is pronounced as in the "original language", therefore it also can be pronounced as "i" (Party, Hobby). <sup>[WIKIPEDIA](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y#Verwendung_im_Deutschen)</sup>

In a nutshell: Besides of proper names there are no German words that have the letter "y". Thus, for the German language itself it is hard to say if it is a vowel or not. For the words from foreign languages we take the pronunciation of the other language. That don't makes the "y" a vowel in the German languages automatically, not least because there are a lot of "exceptions" where it isn't pronounced as vowel. I don't see "y" as a vowel of the German language and that's what you learn in school, too.

---

(*) I just want to mention a few words in which the *y* is spoken as consonant *j*:

- [Yeti](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Yeti) [ˈjeːti]
- [Yoga](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Yoga) [ˈjoːɡa] <sub>(alternative spelling: *Joga*)</sub>
- [Yacht](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Yacht) [jaχt] <sub>(alternative spelling: *Jacht*)</sub>

For the sake of completeness, I shouldn't forget to mention diphthongs:

> ei/ey/ai/ay/au/ao/eu/äu/oi/oy

Comment: There are quite a lot words where “y” serves as a vowel (often words with a greek root): synkron, Synonym, Sympathie, Rhythmus, Lyrik, Tyrann, Mystik,...

Comment: @Clemens As I said: "Note, that the y is just used in foreign words that are adopted to the German Language." Yes, indeed, there are more words than just "Typ", but for all of them the same applies.

Comment: Btw. all those examples are *ü*. If y weren't part of the German Language then I assume that the y of the foreign words would be replaced with the German umlaut.

Comment: @Em1 I have a bit of trouble with "foreign words". If you only go back far enough you can find some foreign root for loads of words, e.g. "Tafel"...

Comment: @Clemens I've no idea what you want to tell me.

Comment: @Em1 Well, I'm just trying to figure out when a word stops being foreign. Do you consider "Tafel" (tabula), "Maschine" (machina) or "Wein" (vinum) also foreign? And if not, why are "typisch" or "sympathisch" foreign then?

Comment: @Clemens That's absolutely not what I said. Maybe it is phrase a bit clumsy, I will rephrase it.

Comment: Well, I guess my point is this: both for the question and for learning German it is completely irrelevant if the words have been adapted some time in the past or not. Just like in English "y" can serve both as a vowel and as a consonant in German.

Comment: Of note, Takkat's Wikipedia reference above also makes the point of "y" being used in words of foreign descent.

Comment: By the way, "y" as "j" may occur in the middle of the word as well, e.g. "Maya" or "Mayonnaise".

Comment: Yeti and Yoga are certainly loan words in German, my impression was that the letter "ypsilon" always has an ü sound except in loan words like those you listed. It may well be the case that Y is rarely used except in loan words, but if it's usually a consonant in non-loan words, then an example native German word that uses it that way would help. Yacht also appears to be a spelling originating from English (the original word and preferred spelling being "Jacht", originally Dutch).

Comment: So, I amended my answer. I hope, I could clarify my point of view.

Comment: @Theodore: Well, as Clemens already pointed out, what would count as a non-loan word -- _typisch?_

Comment: Looking around in Duden, I see nearly all of the words with y have a Greek ancestor (including typisch, Typ), but they are the words pronounced like the "name on the tin" (ypsilon), unlike more recent acquisitions/inventions (Yeti, Handy). I just wanted to say it felt like the answer was arguing that Y should be seen as a consonant (which it almost never is), and it looked like the asker mostly needed to know that y is almost always a vowel (usually ü) in German. Looks good to me now. +1

Comment: @HendrikVogt: I'd say Ymir ( http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ymir ) isn't a loan word, as it comes from German(ic) mythology.

Comment: @Landei: Hmm, _Germanic_ maybe, but rather Scandinavian than German. Moreover, I'd find a _word_ a lot more convincing than a _name_ ... But still interesting - do you know more about _Y_ in Scandinavian languages?

Comment: @HendrikVogt: I'm sorry, I don't know about.

Answer (score 9):

A vowel is really primarily a type of sound rather than a letter.  But the letters used to represent vowels can also be referred to as vowels (Vokalbuchstaben in German).  In both English and German, Y sometimes represents a vowel and sometimes a consonant.

It looks like Y was originally introduced into the Roman alphabet solely for the purpose of transcribing the letter Y (ypsilon) - which is a vowel - in Greek words.  See the following quote from Wikipedia (from the German page on the [Roman alphabet](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lateinisches_Alphabet)):

> "Weitere Veränderungen ergaben sich, nachdem das griechische Mutterland 146 v. Chr. unterworfen und dem Staatsgebiet der Römischen Republik eingegliedert worden war und verstärkter Bedarf entstand, griechische Namen und Fremdwörter in lateinischer Schrift wiederzugeben. Das griechische Ypsilon, das in der etruskischen Schreibform V schon in archaischer Zeit zur Schreibung des Vokals [u] (gemäß dem Lautwert auch im archaischen Griechisch, vgl. lat. burrus < πυρρός „rot”) und des Halbkonsonanten [w] in das lateinische Alphabet übernommen worden, wurde in klassischer Zeit mit dem auch im klassischen Griechisch mittlerweile gegebenen Lautwert [ü] noch einmal, diesmal in der Schreibform Y und aus dem Griechischen direkt, übernommen, blieb hierbei im Lateinischen aber als ein Fremdzeichen für die Schreibung griechischer Namen und Fremdwörter reserviert."

Since Y is called Ypsilon in German, and based on the fact that the only reasonably old German words I know containing Y are actually Greek, I'm guessing that for a while after the Roman alphabet began to be used for German, Y was only used for transcribing Greek words (and therefore only as a vowel), as had been the case in Latin.  But this is only a conjecture.